# Socket.io dynamic "on" binding

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, dom-events

I have this code:

```
var action = "getPost";

clients[socket.id].on(action, function(data) {
            var message = {
                sender : "",
                receiver : "moderation",
                m : {action : action, data: data, socket: socket.id}
            }
            console.log(message);
            console.log("Sockets executing: ", action);
            //process.send(message);
        });

action = "canIGetHoldedPost";

clients[socket.id].on(action, function(data) {
            var message = {
                sender : "",
                receiver : "moderation",
                m : {action : action, data: data, socket: socket.id}
            }
            console.log(message);
            console.log("Sockets executing: ", action);
            //process.send(message);
        });
```

My problem: when I emits one of this functions, it executes with last action value(`"canIGetHoldedPost"`) in the body (`m : {action : "canIGetHoldedPost"`). How can I bind this functions to get expected result?

I can't just write needed action in the body, because it will be a loop with many events, not only two that I wrote here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the use where you need closure, the reason you're not getting the expected value is that by the time callback gets called, the value of `action` gets replaced.

You could probably make a function that binds the event. This way the value of `action` will be preserved till the callback gets executed.

```
var action = "getPost";
bind(action);

action = "canIGetHoldedPost";
bind(action);

function bind(ac) {
    var action = ac;

    clients[socket.id].on(action, function(data) {
        var message = {
                sender : "",
                receiver : "moderation",
                m : {action : action, data: data, socket: socket.id}
        }
        console.log(message);
        console.log("Sockets executing: ", action);
        //process.send(message);
    });
}
```

Comment: "This is the use where you need closure, the reason you're not getting the expected value is that by the time callback gets called, the value of action gets replaced." - I have figured this out, but didn't know how I can override that. Thank you very much!